# Maven Proxy settings.xml ignored

Tags: maven-2, proxy

Maybe someone can help me with the following Problem:

I have declared a proxy in `M` as described at [maven - Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

For some reason the proxy is ignored, although the proxy itself works correctly with maven when setting the proxy via command line.

When calling the maven goal like this, it works:

```
mvn -DproxySet=true -DproxyHost=myproxy.com -DproxyPort=3128 eclipse:eclipse
```

Any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 5):

When `settings.xml` is ignored, I tend to check first if the environment variable **`M2_HOME`**:

- exists in the current shell session
- refers to the parent directory of said `settings.xml`

[mglauche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143652/mglauche) comments:

> `M2_HOME` should specify the **system** `settings.xml` to use.
>   You still have your **user settings** in `${home}/.m2/settings.xml`, which should overwrite anything in the system settings.

---

For Maven Eclipse, as [mglauche](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143652/mglauche) mentions in the comments, specify the full path in the maven preferences:

[image: eclipse maven preferences]

Comment: Also, which settings.xml are you using ? the system one, or the user one ?

Comment: @mglauche: but if you have a `M2_HOME` explicitly set, that would force the `settings.xml` you want to use, no?

Comment: I discovered it seems to be a problem with the "maven eclipse plugin" "mvn install" does use the proxy settings

Comment: The specify the location of your settings.xml in the maven eclipse plugin. (Window->preferences->maven), or better, tell the eclipse plugin to use your external maven version

Comment: @VonC M2_HOME should specify the system settings.xml to use, you still have your user settings in ${home}/.m2/settings.xml, which should overwwrite anything in the system settings.

Comment: @mglauche: got it (and included in the answer). @Grolsch: I have included the Eclipse Maven preferences in the answer, but if you are using the command line, then Eclipse is not the issue here.

Comment: No eclipse is not the issue here but I appreciate the help given so far, for the moment I changed the MAVEN_OPTS in .bashrc to solve the problem for the moment

Comment: thank you for the hint of $M2_HOME presence, in my case in mvn 3.3, if M2_HOME was not set,proxy settings from mvn command line were not taken into use.