# setting maven proxy settings outside of settings.xml

Tags: maven, ant, build

I have a make file that calls ant and maven build files. I've had some trouble setting the proxy settings for maven. because there was no settings.xml file that I could find for this make file. So I created on in the {user.hom}/.m2/ directory where it usually looks for one. This did solve the problem, however when I ran sudo make it did not find this file and started having "connection refused" when it tried to download from remote repositories.

Is there a way to set the Maven proxy settings from within the make file so that I do not have to manually create the settings.xml. Maybe within the pom file or some other way.

It seems like it isn't fully installed but relying on external references for anything that it needs. I have never installed maven or ant and I cannot find the m2_home directory. This make file should be able to run on systems that do not have maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using sudo, the script is executed as user "root" by default. So the proxy-setup should be in the homedir of root. But i think, its not a good idea to run make with root-privileges.

According to the [Maven-Proxy-Example](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) and the [Maven-Pom-Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html), there is no proxy config in Pom.

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828567/maven-proxy-settings) seems to comfirm this. Maybe the `java.net.useSystemProxies` idea can do what you want.

I'm not sure if [this markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828567/maven-proxy-settings) only used by the eclipse plugin or generally by maven itself.

Comment: I stopped running it with sudo but now the make process isn't fully automated because to make it work the user has to add this 'setup.xml' file to the .m2 direcotry. Trying to find out if there is another way.

Comment: You tried the -DproxySet=true optioms from the second linked question?

Comment: I'm setting this as the correct answer only because, technically it's working with settings.xml and your answer helped. I'm still not sure exactly the relationship the make process has to my actual installation of Maven, or if you even need a full installation of Maven and Ant on your computer to run a Make file that takes advantage of them. I'm running some one else's Makefile so I'm not a Make expert but it seems to be temporarily installing Maven for this use.